# Check if NSDate is in current week not working for specific date?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I have tried couple of ways to check if `NSDate` is in current week:

> Method 1

```
func isInThisWeek(date: Date) -> Bool
{
    return Calendar.current.isDate(date, equalTo: Date(), toGranularity: .weekOfYear)
}
```

> Method 2

```
func dateFallsInCurrentWeek(date: Date) -> Bool
{
    let currentWeek = Calendar.current.component(Calendar.Component.weekOfYear, from: Date())
    let datesWeek = Calendar.current.component(Calendar.Component.weekOfYear, from: date)
    return (currentWeek == datesWeek)
}
```

Now here is the case where I am getting `FALSE` though this date is in current week.

[image]

I tested on: `Monday, August 10, 2020 6:00:00 PM (My time zone: +5:30 GMT)`. So as per calendar, this date belongs to `10 Aug - 16 Aug` week.

What may be wrong? In my iPad in which I am testing this, has starting day of Week is `Monday` as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All calendars would consider sunday as the first weekday. If you would like to consider monday as the start of your week you need to use iso8601 calendar.

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1597516200) // .description  // "2020-08-15 18:30:00 +0000"
let tz = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 5*3600 + 1800)!  // GMT+0530 (fixed)
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: tz, from: date)
components.day      // 16
components.weekday  // Sunday
// Current Calendar starts on sunday so it goes from 9...15 and 16...22
// To get the current week starting on monday you need iso8601 calendar
let equalToDate = DateComponents(calendar: .current, timeZone: tz, year: 2020, month: 8, day: 10, hour: 18).date!
equalToDate.description  // "2020-08-10 12:30:00 +0000"
Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).isDate(date, equalTo: equalToDate, toGranularity: .weekOfYear)  // true
```

Comment: It worked... I have just changed `Calendar.current` to `Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)`. Is that only thing I need to change? Because you have wrote some other lines of code in answer as well.

Comment: Answer upvoted and accepted as it fulfills my need..

Comment: Yes the rest of the code was just trying to replicate your scenario.